# Align Bootstrap cards in 3x 3 grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
              <p class="card-text"> Something to Write about </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Something</a>
       </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

This is the code for one of the card and the same is iterated 8 times more to get 9 card decks but I am getting all in one single line. How to get that?

Comment: Can you please post the code you already have?

Comment: Enter your code...